# NDSolve with parameter

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica and probably the thing I am looking for is straightforward, I tried some approaches but I couldn't succeed.

I have a DE and I want to have a solution parametrized by the parameter of DE. More precisely,
Let's define the DE as:
`x'=f[x,t,a]` where "a" is the parameter and I want to have the solution of `x` as a function of time and parameter, which I name the function g as follows.
`x=g[t,a]`

When the DE is basic, it is easy to use `DSolve` and obtain it, but I couldn't find a way to obtain such solution with `NDSolve`. I am aware that `NDSolve` works with only numerical arguements, but I am looking for a way to compare the results with different parameter values.
An easy way to show/compare the results with different parameter values would also be fine.

Comment: Hi! Please visit http://mathematica.stackexchange.com (and register!). A nice Mathematica community there!

Comment: I wonder if any of the closers has been even close to a machine with the Mathematica(TM) language system installed. Surely not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vdp[k_] := {x'@t == y@t, y'@t == -x@t + k (1 - x@t^2) y@t, x@0 == 2, y@0 == 0};
sol = Table[NDSolve[vdp@k, {x, y}, {t, 2000}], {k, 1000, 1500, 100}];
Plot[x@t /. sol, {t, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to run NDSolve several times for different parameter values and then compare the results.